# Check if parameter available in url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

In my form im trying to check if my url have a property called email, and if haves show me the input email in the form with the value already filled, and in case it doesnt give a input email but empty. But im getting "undefined index: email".

My blade html is:

```
<?php
                $email = $_GET['email'];
            ?>
            @if(isset($email))

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email_source" value="{{$email}}">
                </div>

            @else
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email_source" value="">
                </div>
             @endif
```

In my url there cand have 2 situations:

```
http://domain.com/surveys/9/show   (no email)
and
http://domain.com/surveys/9/show?email=someemail@gmail.com   (with email)
```

Someone have a idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Please upload the controller's method which return this view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$email = isset($_GET["email"]) ? $_GET["email"] : NULL;
```

What it does:

- Initialize $email variable
- Check if $_GET["email"] is set
- If true, set $email to $_GET["email"]
- If false, set $email to NULL

Then proceed to check if $email is set or not.

Straight calling $email = $_GET["email"] will set the variable as an empty string if $_GET["email"] is empty.

Comment: In PHP >= 7.0 you can even do `$email = $_GET['email'] ?? null;`. See [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

Comment: @ChrisMagnussen thanks for that! I'm still migrating myself to PHP7 and that will come handy